# Unix remove duplicates,sort and display the max count

Tags: unix

```
3/12/2013 12:00 639 Count
3/12/2013 12:06 693 Count
3/12/2013 12:12 636 Count
3/12/2013 12:18 649 Count
3/12/2013 12:24 658 Count
3/12/2013 12:30 926 Count
3/12/2013 12:36 721 Count
3/12/2013 12:42 797 Count
3/12/2013 12:48 717 Count
3/12/2013 12:00 639 Count
3/12/2013 12:06 700 Count
3/12/2013 12:12 636 Count
3/12/2013 12:18 649 Count
3/12/2013 12:24 658 Count
3/12/2013 12:30 726 Count
3/12/2013 12:36 721 Count
3/12/2013 12:42 850 Count
3/12/2013 12:48 900 Count
3/12/2013 12:00 639 Count
3/12/2013 12:06 693 Count
3/12/2013 12:12 636 Count
3/12/2013 12:18 649 Count
3/12/2013 12:24 658 Count
3/12/2013 12:30 926 Count
3/12/2013 12:36 721 Count
3/12/2013 12:42 797 Count
3/12/2013 12:48 950 Count
```

Output should look like below:

```
3/12/2013 12:00 639 Count
3/12/2013 12:12 636 Count
3/12/2013 12:18 649 Count
3/12/2013 12:24 658 Count
3/12/2013 12:30 926 Count
3/12/2013 12:36 721 Count
3/12/2013 12:06 700 Count
3/12/2013 12:30 726 Count
3/12/2013 12:42 850 Count
3/12/2013 12:48 900 Count
```

Comment: Please help me soon with unix command

Comment: Is about line from file?

Comment: Please specify the question.

Comment: Before this gets slammed with too many downvotes, the question is reasonably implied by the title and the sample results.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this :

```
sort -u -n -k 3 file.txt
```

### Note

- `-u` stands for *uniq*
- `-n` stands for *numerical sort*
- `-k 3` stands for *sort 3rd column*

Comment: bash-3.00$ cat Task1.txt | sort -k 1,2 -n | uniq

2013-03-12 12:00:00  639  Count
2013-03-12 12:06:00  693  Count
2013-03-12 12:06:00  700  Count
2013-03-12 12:12:00  636  Count
2013-03-12 12:18:00  649  Count
2013-03-12 12:24:00  658  Count
2013-03-12 12:30:00  726  Count
2013-03-12 12:30:00  926  Count
2013-03-12 12:36:00  721  Count
2013-03-12 12:42:00  797  Count
2013-03-12 12:42:00  850  Count
2013-03-12 12:48:00  717  Count
2013-03-12 12:48:00  900  Count
2013-03-12 12:48:00  950  Count

I need the max value under One timestamp

Comment: "please help" by updating your post with all interesting (and properly indented) informations.

Answer (score 0):

If this data is in file `foo`, and you have GNU `sort`, you can do:

```
sort -n -k 3 foo | uniq
```

That will do a numeric sort (`-n`), ascending (default), on the third field (`-k 3`).  Then the whole thing is piped through `uniq` to remove duplicate lines.

**Edit: added uniq.**